# How to wrap text for CButton checkbox if texts overruns the window width MFC?

Tags: c++, checkbox, text, mfc, word-wrap

I have a checkbox that is almost by the end of the width of a window(end of a line) so if I translate the text it overruns the window.

```
 CButton checkbox;
 CString str = "Cropped Value Of CheckBox";
 checkbox.create(str,WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, CRect(0,0,0,0), this, CHECK_ID);
```

Now if the length of str is too long that overruns the window as in screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to wrap this text so that if the length of the checkbox text is too long it will wrap the text in the next line and it flexes according to the size of the window.

Comment: You need to DrawText the button text with DT_CALCRECT to see how tall the rectangle should be and  resize the button accordingly.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't following the Microsoft guideline for Internationalization?  It suggests that you "Design menus and dialog boxes to leave room for text expansion. For example, English strings often expand by 40% when translated into German or Dutch."  Your approach may end up making the dialog control spacing messy.

Comment: The size of the button increases with the size of text. It is the size of the window when we load the window for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BS_MULTILINE` button style.

To set that style use below API function:

```
CButton::SetButtonStyle(UINT nStyle,BOOL bRedraw = TRUE)

checkbox.SetButtonStyle(BS_MULTILINE);
```

Documentation link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1wax6c.aspx#cbutton__setbuttonstyle

Comment: Tried this but it truncates the text not sure why. Also, the multiline was not flexing according to the size of the window i.e. if there is enough space for the text the text was stillshowing in multiline.